В чём разница между Reverse Proxy(Обратным Прокси) и Proxy(Обычным Прокси)?
Я правильно понимаю что суть разницы в том, что Proxy подменяет клиента, а Reverse Proxy подменяет сервер(ы)?
Самое понятное объяснение отличий нашёл здесь.

Proxy подменяет клиентов, т.е. это сервер, который подменяет и защищает и данные и работу клиентов.
Reverse Proxy подменяет сервера, т.е. это сервер, который подменяет и защищает данные и работу других серверов.
